# Android sqlite exception on table creation

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to create a table in onCreate() method but sqlite is throwing exception that syntax is wrong.But if i am trying the same query in Firefox SQLite Manager its creating the table successfully.I dont know what's wrong with my code.The query is following:

```
CREATE TABLE playlistSongs(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
playlist_id INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(playlist_id) REFERENCES playlists(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
song_id INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(song_id) REFERENCES songs(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

**Exception is :**

```
11-22 16:44:58.066: E/AndroidRuntime(11241): Caused by:
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "song_id": syntax error:
CREATE TABLE playlistSongs(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,playlist_id
INTEGER,FOREIGN KEY(playlist_id) REFERENCES playlists(id) ON DELETE
CASCADE,song_id INTEGER,FOREIGN KEY(song_id) REFERENCES songs(id) ON
DELETE CASCADE);
```

Comment: What's the result of `PRAGMA compile_options;` in both databases?

Comment: What is PRAGMA compile_options; ?I really dont know about this and how to use this?

Comment: i think you are supposed to declare foreign keys at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was FOREIGN KEY declaration.I had declare them at the end like this:

> CREATE TABLE playlistSongs(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,playlist_id
>   INTEGER,song_id INTEGER,FOREIGN KEY(playlist_id) REFERENCES
>   playlists(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,FOREIGN KEY(song_id) REFERENCES
>   songs(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);

Thanks to @njzk2